# Braintree API Client Misconfigured: the clientApiUrl provided in the clientToken is invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Braintree API Client Misconfigured: the clientApiUrl provided in the clientToken is invalid.

I am getting that error in my browser log. Node backend with angular front end using Braintree javascript SDK Version 2 with drop in. All tokens and API keys in my domain are verified as working and correct.

Integration

/server/app.js - server side node SDK

```
function startBraintree() {
  app.post('/api/token', function (request, response) {
    gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      response.json({
        "client_token": res.clientToken
      });
      console.log(res.clientToken)
    });
  });
}
.then(startBraintree)
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Braintree', err);
});
```

This does in fact produce a client-token in the server logs. I also match this client-token to the one in the browser console to ensure that I am in fact sending this specific token to the browser -

/client/app/braintree.component.js
This is the client side Braintree.setup integration.

```
export class BraintreeComponent {

      clientToken = this.clientToken;
      // constructor($http) {
      //   this.$http = $http;
      // }

      // $onInit() {
      //   this.$http.post('/api/token')
      //     .then(response => {
      //       this.clientToken = response.data;
      //       console.log(response.data);
      //     });
      // }

      /*@ngInject*/
      constructor($scope, $http) {
        this.$http = $http;
        $scope.hasCalledBack = 'Nope';
        this.$http.post('/api/token')
          .then(response => {
            this.clientToken = response.data;
            console.log(this.clientToken);
            braintree.setup(this.clientToken,
              // Replace this with a client token from your server
              'dropin', {
                container: 'dropin',
                onPaymentMethodReceived: function (obj) {
                  $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.hasCalledBack = 'YEP!';
                    alert('Did the scope variable change? Yes!');
                    console.log(obj)
                  });
                }
              });
          });
       }
    }
```

However if i produce a client-token and declare it as a static value - it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you call the braintree.setup() method with a clientToken that is not the verbatim string returned from the generate() method.

Odds are that you're passing { "client_token": "<clientToken-string>" } to braintree.setup() rather than just "<clientToken-string>".

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to fix this issue?  Thank you.